# Mongoose connection error: what is the difference between timed out and socket closed? and when dose either of them occur?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Recently one of retrieve interfaces in my production environment spent long time to get response or no response.

I use nodejs and mongodb.

Project dependencies are shown blow:

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "2.5.10",
  "iconv-lite": "^0.4.13",
  "ioredis": "^1.15.1",
  "log4js": "^0.6.35",
  "mongoose": "^4.4.13",
  "node-schedule": "~1.0.0",
  "node-xlsx": "^0.4.0",
  "superagent": "3.8.2"
}
```

when I checked the log, it said
[production environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6GBA.png)

I think this error was caused by something wrong with the network, so I setup a similar test environment to have the error occur again.

I use wrk to send requests for a while, during this I set the iptables in order to simulate the situation that something wrong with the network.

However, I get another error.
[test environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejsN7.png)

so my questions are:
1. what is the difference between timed out and socket closed? 
2. When dose either of them occur?

Comment: In your `Production environment` error is your mongoDB is not running, `test environment` i think you are closing the db through the code, so post your code.